# How do you reorder categories on R using fct_recode()

Tags: r, forcats

I keep trying to reorder my variables using this function:

```
ces2019 <- mutate(ces2019,vote_intention = fct_recode(vote_intention,"Certain Not to vote" = "(4) Certain not to vote","Unlikely" = "(3) Unlikely","Likely" = "(2) Likely", "Certain"="(1) Certain","Already voted in advanced poll"= "(5) Already voted in advanced poll") )
```

However I keep getting this error:

```
Problem with `mutate()` column `vote_intention`. ℹ `vote_intention = fct_recode(...)`. ℹ Unknown levels in `f`: (4) Certain not to vote, (3) Unlikely, (2) Likely, (1) Certain
```

also whenever I then do `levels(ces2019$vote_intention)` I keep getting Null

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. Do you mean you are trying to "rename" your factor levels? It would be helpful if you added your data to the question. You could edit and copy-paste the console result of `dput(ces2019$voter_intention)`

Comment: I can only reproduce you error when I run your code twice. With made-up data the code seems to run correctly the first time, but if you re-run code again `ces2019` has the updated factor labels, and throws the same error, which makes sense since it's telling us the old levels are not observed in the data.  Could this be the problem?